# Stripe disconnect a connected account with Python SDK

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm trying to disconnected a connected Stripe account from my app using the Stripe Python SDK. Note: I do not want to fully delete the user's Stripe account (which I shouldn't have permission to do anyway) I just want to disconnect it from my Stripe app.

```
import stripe

stripe.api_key = STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

# Get the account to be disconnected
account = stripe.Account.retrieve(id='acct_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')

# Delete I think is NOT what I need
account.delete()
```

Maybe `account.deauthorize()` is what I need?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disconnect an account, you'd use OAuth: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference

If you want to reject an account (say they are fraudulent) you'd use the reject endpoint: https://stripe.com/docs/api/account/reject